# Android: Speed up dynamic UI generation

Tags: android

I have the following class which generates a calendar view. I'm not too fond of the built-in one, and am trying to gain more control over its appearance. However rendering the new UI (e.g. upon swipe) is taking 1-2 seconds to draw. Is there any place I could speed this up? Am testing on HTC One S (2012 model)

Should be relatively straightforward to follow:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RectShape;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calendar extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocalDate _currentSelectedDate = new LocalDate();;
    private LocalDate _today = new LocalDate();;

    private float x1 = 0;
    private float x2 = 0;
    private float y1 = 0;
    private float y2 = 0;

    private TableLayout _tableLayout;
    private RelativeLayout _relativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
        _relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.calendarLayout);


        recreateUI(_currentSelectedDate.getYear(), _currentSelectedDate.getMonthOfYear());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                x1 = touchevent.getX();
                y1 = touchevent.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                x2 = touchevent.getX();
                y2 = touchevent.getY();

                // up
                if (y1 > y2)
                {
                    _currentSelectedDate = _currentSelectedDate.plusMonths(1);
                    recreateUI(_currentSelectedDate.getYear(), _currentSelectedDate.getMonthOfYear());
                }
                // down
                if (y1 < y2)
                {
                    _currentSelectedDate = _currentSelectedDate.minusMonths(1);
                    recreateUI(_currentSelectedDate.getYear(), _currentSelectedDate.getMonthOfYear());
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void recreateUI(int year, int month)
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        _tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        _tableLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        _tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        _relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
        _relativeLayout.addView(_tableLayout);

        LocalDate date = new LocalDate().withYear(year).withMonthOfYear(month).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
        LocalDate last = date.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();

        addMonthNameToUi(date);
        addDaysNamesToUi();
        addDayNumberssToUi(date, last);
    }


    private void addMonthNameToUi(LocalDate date) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.span = 7;

        TextView t = new TextView(this);

        t.setLayoutParams(params);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        t.setText(date.toString("MMM yyyy"));
        row.addView(t);

        float d = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int margin = (int)(20 * d);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) t.getLayoutParams();

        mlp.setMargins(mlp.leftMargin, mlp.topMargin, mlp.rightMargin, margin);

        _tableLayout.addView(row);
    }

    private void addDaysNamesToUi() {
        TableRow dayNameRow = new TableRow(this);

        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Mon");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Tue");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Wed");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Thu");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Fri");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Sat");
        addMonth(dayNameRow, "Sun");

        _tableLayout.addView(dayNameRow);
    }

    private void addDayNumberssToUi(LocalDate date, LocalDate last) {
        TableRow row = null;
        int columnsCount = 0;
        boolean firstRow = true;

        while (date.isBefore(last) || date.isEqual(last)) {
            if (columnsCount == 0) {
                row = new TableRow(this);

                _tableLayout.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));

                // blank columns for days not at the start of month
                if (firstRow) {
                    firstRow = false;
                    int i = 1;
                    for (; i < date.getDayOfWeek(); i++) {
                        addDayNumberToRow(row, date, "");
                    }

                    columnsCount += i - 1;
                    date.plusDays(i - 1);
                }
            }

            addDayNumberToRow(row, date, String.valueOf(date.getDayOfMonth()));

            date = date.plusDays(1);
            columnsCount++;

            if (columnsCount == 7)
                columnsCount = 0;
        }

        while (row.getChildCount() < 7)
            addDayNumberToRow(row, date, "");
    }


    private void addMonth(TableRow row, String month)
    {
        TextView t = new TextView(this);

        t.setText(month);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        row.addView(t);
    }

    private void addDayNumberToRow(TableRow row, final LocalDate date, String text)
    {
        TextView v = new TextView(this);
        v.setText(text);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));

        if (date.getDayOfMonth() == _today.getDayOfMonth() && date.getMonthOfYear() == _today.getMonthOfYear() && date.getYear() == _today.getYear()) {
            v.setTypeface(v.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            v.setTextSize(v.getTextSize() + 1);
        }

        ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        border.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        border.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

        v.setBackground(border);
        row.addView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use method tracing to determine exactly where you are spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your "recreateUI" method do alot of stuff like creating new views. Avoid creating new objects by reusing those already created.

Usually calendar views are quite complex. You most likely wont achieve smooth framerate by using multiple views in such way. You would have to write custom view witch will draw itself.

Comment: Hmm, the speed seems to be fine, today. Perhaps my device was running a little behind, at the time ....odd!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out a lot of the slowdown was caused from running the application under debug mode -- running it normally resulted in acceptable performance.